# How can I lookup in Google Sheets using using a regex match from two columns and one vlookup/ Array

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, vlookup, flatten

[Lookup Up Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNasW.png)

In column G, row 3 I want to lookup Package weight 7 (Column D) containing the first words from Columns C and E ("Rural" and "South").

I want to look that combination up in here:
[Formula Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBM8u.png)

I want to look up Package Weight 7 in Column A and I want to look up  match for "Rural" and "South" in the Row 2 Headers.

I want the answer to this query to be F8's value (20).

The following Sheet is editable in the formula column:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PYZ8bQmH9mzwHL4v19VbbJ9aXs3kbn0BhRNRKppxOe0/edit?usp=sharing

Can you help??? Ive tried variations of

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(x, "South"), x, x)
```

=ArrayFormula(vlookup(xxxxx))

But its too complex for this brain.

Comment: Weight 7 and South Island Rural have a value of 20, not 14 though

Comment: So true @CAustin, Ive amended sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C&" "&REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "Rural|Urban"), 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(DISTRIBUTION_COSTS!A2:A8&DISTRIBUTION_COSTS!C1:F1&"×"&DISTRIBUTION_COSTS!C2:F8), "×"), 2, ))
```

[image]

Comment: That is some serious skills player0 , very impressed. Thank so much! Nailed it!